# How to restructure a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm having problem with my array basicly this is what i have:

```
$test = 
array(
  "image" => array(
        "name" => array(
            "name.jpg",
            "name2.jpg",
            "name3.jpg"
        ),
        "type"  => array(
                "image/jpeg",
                "image/jpeg",
                "image/jpeg",
        ),
        "size" => array(
          118108,
          589788,
          1387074
        )
    )
)
```

And this is what i would like to have:

```
$test2 =
array(
    "0" => array(
        "name" => "name.jpg",
        "type" => "image/jpeg",
        "size" => 118108
    ),
    "1" => array(
        "name" => "name2.jpg",
        "type" => "image/jpeg",
        "size" => 589788
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "name" => "name3.jpg",
        "type" => "image/jpeg",
        "size" => 1387074
    )

)
```

So i need some kind of script which would redo that first array structure in to the second one

Comment: actualy nothing in specific i've just googled some random scripts but i can't find what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more generic solution. It will rebuild an array with any property names. I also wrapped it in a function to make it easier to use.

Using:

```
function func(array $input)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($input as $type => $properties) {
        foreach ($properties as $name => $values) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
                $result[$i][$name] = $values[$i];
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [size] => 118108
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name2.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [size] => 589788
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => name3.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [size] => 1387074
        )

)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

i think this does it:

```
<?php

$result = array();

foreach($test['image'] as $key=>$data){
foreach($data as $id=>$val){
    $result[$id][$key] = $val;
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$test = 
array(
  "image" => array(
        "name" => array(
            "name.jpg",
            "name2.jpg",
            "name3.jpg"
        ),
        "type"  => array(
                "image/jpeg",
                "image/jpeg",
                "image/jpeg",
        ),
        "size" => array(
          118108,
          589788,
          1387074
        )
    )
);

$output=array();

foreach(range(0,(count($test["image"])-1)) as $i)
{
  $output[$i]=array($test["image"]["name"][$i],$test["image"]["type"][$i],$test["image"]["size"][$i]);
}

var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP syntax allow several ways to do this, for example foreach loop (key are always the same for items):

```
$output = array();
foreach( $test["image"]["name"] as $key => $name){
  $output[] = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'type' => $test["image"]["type"][$key],
    'size' => $test["image"]["size"][$key],
  );
}
```

Or use `array_shift`/`array_pop` in "bad looking" while condition:

```
while(
  ($name = array_pop( $test["image"]["name"])) &&
  ($type = array_pop( $test["image"]["type"])) &&
  ($size = array_pop( $test["image"]["size"]))
) {
    $output[] = array(
      'name' => $name,
      'type' => $type,
      'size' => $size,
    );
}
```

The second one will destroy input array and it's little harder to read than the first one, but it makes sure there won't be problem with not existing array keys.